# How do I implement a foldable instance for Constant a b = Constant a?

Tags: haskell, types, foldable

I want to implement foldable for

```
data Constant a b = Constant a
```

This is my straightforward attempt:

```
instance Foldable (Constant a) where
  foldr f b (Constant a) = f a b
```

The part of the compilation error I want to understand is:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘a1’ with actual type ‘a’
‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature for
foldr :: (a1 -> b -> b) -> b -> Constant a a1 -> b
```

as you can see the folding function takes the "phantom type" (?) `a1` from the Constant which I do not have access to; I only have access to the `a`.

How do I solve this? Please do explain your solution, because I am rather confused.

The whole compilation error is:

```
try2/chap20/ex1.hs:9:30: Couldn't match expected type ‘a1’ with actual type ‘a’ …
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the instance declaration
          at /Users/moron/code/haskell/book/try2/chap20/ex1.hs:8:10
      ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
           the type signature for
             foldr :: (a1 -> b -> b) -> b -> Constant a a1 -> b
           at /Users/moron/code/haskell/book/try2/chap20/ex1.hs:9:3
    Relevant bindings include
      a :: a
        (bound at /Users/moron/code/haskell/book/try2/chap20/ex1.hs:9:23)
      f :: a1 -> b -> b
        (bound at /Users/moron/code/haskell/book/try2/chap20/ex1.hs:9:9)
      foldr :: (a1 -> b -> b) -> b -> Constant a a1 -> b
        (bound at /Users/moron/code/haskell/book/try2/chap20/ex1.hs:9:3)
    In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘a’
    In the expression: f a b
Compilation failed.
```

Comment: You can not. You can only define a `Foldable (C a)` instance for `data C a b = C b`. In your case, you would need something like `instance Foldable (\a -> Constant a b)` but we do not have type-level lambdas in Haskell.

Comment: Great question, I was just wondering this while trying to implement foldl

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Constant a b` doesn't contain any `b`-s, so we fold over it as if it were an empty list of `b`-s:

```
instance Foldable (Constant a) where
    foldr f z (Constant a) = z
```

`a` in `Constant a b` is not relevant to the `Foldable` instance, since that only concerns the last parameter. Hence you can't really make use of `a` in your definition.

Answer (score 2):

I think the only possibility is:

```
data Constant a b = C a

-- foldMap :: Monoid m => (b -> m) -> t b -> m
instance Foldable (Constant a) where
  foldMap f (C a) = mempty
```

which is the trivial solution.

It might be instructive to see why you can do it for this definition:

```
data Constant' a b = C' b

-- foldMap :: Monoid m => (b -> m) -> t b -> m
instance Foldable (Constant' a) where
  foldMap f (C' a) = f a
```

Here `t` is `Constant' a`, so

- the type `t b` is `Constant' a b`. Values of this type have the structure `C bval` for some value `bval` of type `b`.
- `f` has type `b -> m`, so we can apply `f` to `bval`

In the other case, though, we don't have a value from `b` to apply to `f`, so the best we can do is return `mempty`.